# I have ConfigParser.NoOptionError in my backup-mysql.py

Tags: python, mysql, configparser

I created python file **backup-mysql.py** and after ***./ backup-mysql.py*** I have ***ConfigParser.NoOptionError***

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Importing the modules
import os
import ConfigParser
import time

# On Debian, /etc/mysql/debian.cnf contains 'root' a like login and password.
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/etc/mysql/debian.cnf")
username = config.get('client', 'root')
password = config.get('client', 'password')
hostname = config.get('client', 'localhost')
filestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Get a list of databases with :
database_list_command="mysql -u %s -p%s -h %s --silent -N -e 'show databases'" % (username, password, hostname)
for database in os.popen(database_list_command).readlines():
    database = database.strip()
    if database == 'information_schema':
        continue
    if database == 'performance_schema':
        continue
    filename = "/backups/mysql/%s-%s.sql" % (database, filestamp)
    os.popen("mysqldump --single-transaction -u %s -p%s -h %s -d %s | gzip -c > %s.gz" % (username, password, hostname, database, filename))
```

and after ***./ backup-mysql.py***

```
root@rd:/home/pi/apps# ./backup-mysql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./backup-mysql.py", line 10, in <module>
    username = config.get('client', 'root')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 618, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'root' in section: 'client'
root@rd:/home/pi/apps# nano backup-mysql.py
root@rd:/home/pi/apps# ./backup-mysql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./backup-mysql.py", line 10, in <module>
    username = config.get('client', 'root')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 618, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'root' in section: 'client'
root@rd:/home/pi/apps#
```

I have root user. I do not now what is wrong?

More info about debian.cnf file

```
root@rd:/home/pi/apps# cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

This body do not want to much code

Comment: The error you get is not about you executing this script as root or not. I tells you the line number to look at: `File "./backup-mysql.py", line 10, in <module>` and also tells you what went wrong exactly: `No option 'root' in section: 'client'`.  So the data you try to read is not present in the file /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.  Can you post that file as well?

Comment: Please post it to your question. The text is not readable in the comment.

Comment: I added cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

Answer (score 0):

Your error message reads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./backup-mysql.py", line 10, in <module>
    username = config.get('client', 'root')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 618, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'root' in section: 'client'
```

First this tells you where the error happend: in line 10. Your line 10 says

```py
username = config.get('client', 'root')
```

So you are trying to read a field named "root" from a section named "client".  The error message tells you what went wrong at the bottom: `No option 'root' in section: 'client'`.

Looking at the file you are trying to read you can see that there is indeed no option "root" in "client":

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I suspect you are really trying to read the "user" option.  So change line 10 to

```py
username = config.get('client', 'user')
```

Also line 12 should probably read the "host" option and not the "localhost" option as this also does not exist.

Comment: I follow one step forward. After execute ./backup-mysql.py. I have ```
Enter password:```  I write password  and there is loop ```Enter password:
Enter password:
Enter password:```

Comment: Password is correct ```mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect```

Comment: Your question seems to  change over time. I think the original question is answered. If so you can accept the answer. I think your next problem is about connecting to the database. You could start a new question if you can not figure out on your own what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/4102092/lucas   is done. The loop is becouse there is so much databases. to each database is password